# Is it possible to convert between two case class with different name and slightly different field in scala

Tags: scala

for example, I have case classes

```
case class foo(timestamp:String, epochSecond: Long)
```

and

```
case class bar(epochSecond: Long, timestamp:String)
```

Is it possible to make conversion between the instance of these two classes?

Comment: Why don't you write a conversion function to do that? Is that not what you are looking for?

Comment: Shapeless could probable help you out here.

Comment: There are numerous ways to do so - could you please specify what other considerations do you have? For instance, simplest would be to have a utility object to convert between the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is rather vague because there are so many ways to accomplish this. Here's one option.

With the definition of the case classes ...

```
case class Foo(timestamp:String, epochSecond: Long)
case class Bar(epochSecond: Long, timestamp:String)
```

... add auxiliary factory methods.

```
object Foo {
  def apply(b: Bar): Foo = this(b.timestamp, b.epochSecond)
}
object Bar {
  def apply(f: Foo): Bar = this(f.epochSecond, f.timestamp)
}
```

Now you can transition from one type to the other very simply.

```
val fooX = Foo("noon", 42L)
val barY = Bar(99L, "none")

val fooY = Foo(barY)  //fooY: Foo = Foo(none,99)
val barX = Bar(fooX)  //barX: Bar = Bar(42,noon)
```